# My head is being rendered in the body of my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I recently switched to a virtual host (on a windows machine) and my local alias is now example.dev

After doing this, I found that my `<head>` is being rendered in the body. I tried changing my file encodings to UTF-8 but that did not work.

Comment: Is it only being rendered within the `<body>` or is it rendered twice? Does it happen across all post types? Which theme file is being used and where is `get_header()` in that file?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to change the encoding to UTF-8 for the whole project by following the answer that is here [How to change encoding of all files at once with Jetbrains IDE like WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451646/how-to-change-encoding-of-all-files-at-once-with-jetbrains-ide-like-webstorm)